# How to you send the left or right track only of a media player to both left and right output? (preferably in VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, audio, windows-media-player

So, I have an MP3 with two people having a conversation person A on the left and person B on the right. I want to be able to isolate either one of them, and hear it across both ears (in headphone). If I have both A & B on, I want to hear both in both ears (ie mono). I'm going to be doing it in vb.net. Can someone point me to the right direction?

I did look at Windows Media Player think about using something like mp3Player1.settings.balance=-100 but that would only play on once side of the headphones.

I'm thinking I would need combine the above with something that would allow me to send the left headphone output to the right headphone output???

Comment: Maybe [StereoToMonoProvider16](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/ConvertBetweenStereoAndMono.md) from [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) will do what you need; I haven't used it.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, I've always been under the assumption that the channel (left/right) sound is played on is built into the media file and whatever plays it has at best very limited control.

Comment: @Hursey as far as the track playing that is correct, when you pause left it pauses the right too, when you hit play, they both play. Both tracks always remain in sync. What I need is more about volume control and routing of the audio.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you. I will take a look at that NAudio I think the library in general will be of interest.